# How to split on commas except when they're in brackets without Lookarounds?

Tags: regex, string, go

There are a lot of similar questions to this and unfortunately, none of those solutions work.

This contains an example of input and a completely working regex:
https://regex101.com/r/yAKe7l/1

(copy and pasted from the link below)

Regex: `,(?!([^<]*>[^>]*>))`

Sample:

```
Hello, Fellow, Humans,
How, are ,<,>, you,
Hello<my, fellow>
Hello "please to meat, you"

Deeploy, <<nested, >> comments,
```

It correctly selects only the commas outside of any <>

The issue:
The language I am using (GO) does not allow look-ahead or look-behind

Is there a way to eloquently split by comma with regex?
Or will I have to manually implement a look behind or some sort of check for matching <>

My goal would be something like:

```
split := compiledRegex.Split("Example string, With <Deeply, Nested Comments> split, up", -1)
split = ["Example string", "With <Deeply, Nested Comments> split", "up"]
```

Comment: FYI your current regex with lookarounds does not actually work, as it would incorrectly match commas inside the outer brackets of `,<,<,>,<,>,>,`: https://regex101.com/r/yAKe7l/2 The only way to properly deal with balanced nested constructs with regex is to use a regex engine that supports [capturing group recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), which golang does not have built-in.

Comment: Try https://play.golang.org/p/9c2XWmYjrih, ``matches := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:<+[^<>]*>+|[^,])+`).FindAllString(text, -1)``

Comment: Regex is probably the worst possible way to attempt this. A state machine parser would be a better solution, especially if you want to have any way to escape the brackets or commas.

Comment: If the brackets are quotes instead, you can use CSV https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv would that work?